# Question: the probability of Gaussian process increments

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

I have a question about increments of Gaussian process.

I think I am confused with the concept if Random variable and process.. :-(

**Could I express a only one expression below the probability?**

```
Assuming X(t) is Gaussian process with stationary increment, not independent increment.

Y(t) is the process from the increment of X(t).

Y(t) = {X(1)-X(0), X(2)-X(1), X(3)-X(2), ... }
     = {Y(0), Y(1), Y(2), ...}

Then, the elements of Y(t) is Gaussian random variable with correlation.

Assuming each variable of Y(t) is following standard normal distribution.
```

How can I express **the probability 
that the samples from the process is larger than constant number c 
over the entire process Y(t)?**

I want to say it over the entire process, not over the specific time slot.

I think P(Y(t) > c) is incorrect

and P(Y(1) > c) is also incorrect, I think.

I agonized with this problem for a week but I cannot solve it..

Please give me a little help!!

Comment: If anything, $Y = (Y_t)_{t\in N} = \{X_1-X_0, X_2-X_1, ...\}$, where $Y$ is the process we are talking about. You are confusing the process with it at a certain time. It's like confusing function $f$ with its value at $x$, $f(x)$.

Comment: $P(\forall_{t\in N} Y_t > c)$ is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Jakobian I really really really appreciate you! Is there a specific name of this probability?

Comment: Not that I know, but you could say it's the probability that the trajectory of the process lies above the line $y = c$.

Comment: @Jakobian I see. Then I have to study the trajectory of stochastic process. Thank you so much!